# Rails caching gives wrong response format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I am using ETag caching for a **Rails (4.1.1)** action with the `stale?` method; however it does not take the request format into consideration. Example: if `/stations.json` has been loaded by the user and they then click a link to `/stations` they will get a cached JSON response instead of html.

Am I doing it wrong or is this a Rails bug?

```
# GET /stations
# GET /stations.json
def index
  @title = "Stations"
  @last_updated = Station.order("updated_at asc").last

  if stale?(@last_updated, last_modified: @last_updated.try(:updated_at))
    @stations = all_with_latest_observation
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @stations }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where did you set your cache? show your code.

Comment: @dddd1919: [`stale?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/stale%3F)

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not familiar with rails4 function. Looks like `stale` will judge your params to decide if return `304`, would you try to skip `stale?` when request json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug in ActionPack](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17129)

I found a workaround

```
class ApplicationController 
  etag { request.format }
end
```

And of course the spec:

```
describe StationsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    describe "ETag" do
      before { get :index, format: 'json' }
      it "should not use the same ETag for different content types" do
        get :index, format: 'json'
        first_response = response.headers.clone
        get :index, format: 'html'
        expect(first_response['ETag']).to_not eq (response.headers['ETag'])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the key :etag when you call stale? method.

```
# GET /stations
# GET /stations.json
def index
 @title = "Stations"
 @last_updated = Station.order("updated_at asc").last

 if stale?(etag: @last_updated, last_modified: @last_updated.try(:updated_at))
   @stations = all_with_latest_observation
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @stations }
   end
 end
end
```

Then let's see what's happen!

Comment: This seems to fix the issue, not sure why though since [stale?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b40bd16b7b0810b9d5621339f243c4a9569ceb96/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/conditional_get.rb#L136) can take a resource as a first parameter.